# How to generate each query in a separate SQL file using TPC-DS dsqgen tool?

Tags: benchmark, netezza

I'm using TPC-DS dsqgen to translate its templates to runnable queries.

I tried the following argument variations to save each query in a dedicated `.sql` file, but they all save the runnable query in `query_0.sql`, even if I'm using a template other than `query1.tpl`!

```
$ ./dsqgen -v -out ../output/queries -dir ../query_templates -dialect netezza -input ../query_templates/templates.lst
qgen2 Query Generator (Version 3.2.0)
Copyright Transaction Processing Performance Council (TPC) 2001 - 2021
Warning: This scale factor is valid for QUALIFICATION ONLY
Parsed 99 templates

$ ls -ltrh ../output/queries
total 156K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mgelbana mgelbana 156K Feb  9 20:42 query_0.sql

$ ./dsqgen -v -out ../output/queries -dir ../query_templates -dialect netezza -template ../query_templates/query2.tpl
qgen2 Query Generator (Version 3.2.0)
Copyright Transaction Processing Performance Council (TPC) 2001 - 2021
Parsed 1 templates

$ ls -ltrh ../output/queries
total 4.0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mgelbana mgelbana 2.1K Feb  9 20:44 query_0.sql
```

So regardless if I pick a particular template or just choose to process all templates, I'll still get the output written in a single file by the exact same name every time!

So how can I direct this tool to output the generated runnable SQL query in a dedicated `.sql` file names after the associated template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used tpc-ds v3.2.0
Has several bugs. One of them is the issue you noted above (generating query to same file!).
To save you time here is the complete bash script to generate queries from templates along with variants for Netezza
You need to edit the script to set some variables/paths, that's all.
Let me know if any concern. Good luck!

```
#! /bin/bash

function usage
{
    echo "$0 <scale>"
    echo "    scale in GB is one of 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000, 100000"
    echo ""
    exit
} # end function usage

function fix_query_template
{
    # add following line to beginning of each query template file
    #define _END = "";
    for file in $(find $TEMPLATEDIR -name "query*.tpl")
    do
        echo Processing $file
        # Remove line if exists
        sed -i '/^define _END = "";/d' $file
        # Add line to beginning
        sed -i '1s/^/define _END = "";\n/' $file
    done
} # end function fix_query_template

function fix_netezza_template
{
    # append 'define _END = "";' to netezza.tpl
    file="$TEMPLATEDIR/netezza.tpl"
    echo Processing $file
    # Remove line if exists
    sed -i '/^define _END = "";/d' $file
    # Append line to file
    echo 'define _END = "";' >> $file
} # end function fix_netezza_template

function gen_query_alt
{
    # Generate queries from template for given scale
    for i in `seq 1 99`
    do
        j=$(printf "%03d" $i) #i=1 j=001

        cmd="echo query${i}.tpl > $TEMPLATEDIR/templates_${i}.lst"
        echo "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"

        cmd="$TOOLSDIR/dsqgen -directory $TEMPLATEDIR -input $TEMPLATEDIR/templates_${i}.lst -distributions $TOOLSDIR/tpcds.idx -verbose y -qualify y -scale $SCALE -dialect netezza -output_dir $OUTDIR -rngseed $SEED"
        echo "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"

        cmd="mv $MV_OPTION $OUTDIR/query_0.sql $OUTDIR/query${j}.sql"
        echo "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"
        echo ""
    done
} # end function gen_query_alt

function gen_query
{
    # Generate queries from template for given scale
    pushd $TOOLSDIR
    for fullfile in `ls $TEMPLATEDIR/query*.tpl`
    do
        echo $fullfile
        filename=$(basename -- "$fullfile")
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        i=`echo "$filename"|cut -c 6-`

        j=$(printf "%03d" $i)
        # filename=query9 i=9 j=009
        #echo $filename $i $j

        \rm -f $OUTDIR/query_0.sql
        #cmd="./dsqgen -directory ../query_templates -template query${i}.tpl -distributions $TOOLSDIR/tpcds.idx -verbose y -qualify y -scale $SCALE -dialect netezza -output_dir $OUTDIR -rngseed $SEED"
        cmd="./dsqgen -directory ../query_templates -template query${i}.tpl -verbose y -scale $SCALE -dialect netezza -output_dir $OUTDIR -rngseed $SEED"
        echo "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"

        cmd="mv $MV_OPTION $OUTDIR/query_0.sql $OUTDIR/query${j}.sql"
        echo "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"
        echo ""
    done
    popd
} # end function gen_query

function gen_query_variant
{
    # Generate query variants from template for given scale
    pushd $TOOLSDIR
    \cp $TEMPLATEDIR/netezza.tpl $TEMPLATEVARIANTDIR/netezza.tpl
    for fullfile in `ls $TEMPLATEVARIANTDIR/query*.tpl`
    do
        echo $fullfile
        filename=$(basename -- "$fullfile")
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        lastchar=`echo "${filename: -1}"`
        i=`echo "$filename"|rev|cut -c 2-|rev|cut -c 6-`
        j=$(printf "%03d" $i)
        # filename=query10a i=10 j=010 lastchar=a
        #echo $filename $i $j $lastchar

        cmd="./dsqgen -directory ../query_variants -template query${i}${lastchar}.tpl -verbose y -scale $SCALE -dialect netezza -output_dir $OUTDIR -rngseed $SEED"
        echo "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"

        cmd="mv $MV_OPTION $OUTDIR/query_0.sql $OUTDIR/query${j}${lastchar}.sql"
        echo "$cmd"; eval "$cmd"
        echo ""
    done
    popd
} # end function gen_query_variant

function fix_query
{
    # Generate queries from template for given scale
    for f in `ls $OUTDIR/*.sql`
    do
        # Change file in-place
        # Match lines that don't have 'interval'
        # Search for pattern '(one or more space)(one or more digits)(one or more space)days'
        # Replace with " interval '(digits matched) days'"
        # e.g. change "  14 days" to  "interval '14 days'"
        # query030.sql has an error, c_last_review_date_sk should be c_last_review_date
        cmd="sed -i -E -e \"/interval/!s/([ ]+)([0-9]+)([ ]+)days/ interval '\2 days'/gi\" -e \"s/c_last_review_date_sk/c_last_review_date/gi\" $f"
        echo "$cmd"
        eval "$cmd"

        cmd="chmod 444 $f"
        echo "$cmd"
        eval "$cmd"
    done
} # end function fix_query

#-----------------------------------------------
# Main
#-----------------------------------------------

if [ "$#" != 1 ] || [ "$1" == "-h" ]
then
    usage
fi

SCALE="$1" # in GB
case $SCALE in
    100 | 300 | 1000 | 3000 | 10000 | 30000 | 100000) ;;
    *) usage ;;
esac

SCRIPTDIR=$PWD
BASEDIR="$SCRIPTDIR/.."
TOOLSDIR="$BASEDIR/DSGen-software-code-3.2.0rc1/tools"
TEMPLATEDIR="$BASEDIR/DSGen-software-code-3.2.0rc1/query_templates"
TEMPLATEVARIANTDIR="$BASEDIR/DSGen-software-code-3.2.0rc1/query_variants"
OUTDIR="$BASEDIR/sql/$SCALE"
OVERWRITE=yes
MV_OPTION=" -n " # no clobber

if [ ! -d "$TOOLSDIR" ]
then
    echo "Error: $TOOLSDIR is missing"
    exit
fi

if [ ! -d "$TEMPLATEDIR" ]
then
    echo "Error: $TEMPLATEDIR is missing"
    exit
fi

if [ "$OVERWRITE" = "yes" ]
then
    MV_OPTION=" -f "
else
    MV_OPTION=" -n " # no clobber
    if [ -d "$OUTDIR" ]
    then
        echo "Error: $OUTDIR already exists, I won't overwrite"
        exit
    fi
fi

mkdir -p $OUTDIR

# Default value for rngseed in qgen_params.h and params.h in
# tpc-ds_v3.2.0_compiled/DSGen-software-code-3.2.0rc1/tools
SEED="19620718"

# -----------------------------
# Don't run these
# -----------------------------
# No need to fix each query template, instead just fix netezza template
#fix_query_template
#gen_query_alt # Alternative to gen_query

# -----------------------------
# Run these
# -----------------------------
# echo "We should not be running these because we have already generated the queries! Hence exiting." && exit
fix_netezza_template
gen_query
gen_query_variant
fix_query
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I admit that I had to do a similar thing to achieve my goal but you shared here is too much of an overkill for me but I'll accept it as it holds very useful tools.